# How to set LocateMe Widget static or predefined location(or x & y)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I want to have locateMe button with static predefined x and y coordinates.

I have found this:

```
myWidget = new locateButton({
theme: "locateButton", // (optional). class name for the widget container. default: "locateButton"
map: myMap, // (required) map object. default: null.
visible: true, // (optional) show the widget. default: true.
highlightLocation: true, // (optional) show a graphic on the location when geolocated. default: true.
scale: null, // (optional) scale in meters to geolocate to. Defaults to accuracy from geolocation.
symbol: new PictureMarkerSymbol(require.toUrl("esri/dijit") + '/images/blue-dot.png', 21, 21), // (optional)
infoTemplate: null, // (optional) popup info template. default: null
useTracking: true, // (optional) use watchPosition instead of getCurrentLocation. default: false
setScale: true, // (optional) set scale on locate. default: true.
centerAt: true, // (optional) center at point on locate. default: true
geolocationOptions: // (optional). default: { maximumAge: 0, timeout: 15000, enableHighAccuracy: true}}, "locateButton");myWidget.startup();
```

But I can't make it run.

Any help how to achieve the LocateMe button with predefined values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `locateButton` widget is designed for retrieving the dynamic locations of end users using [HTML5 geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation).

if you want a button which centers the map on a static location, please check out the [`homeButton`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/widget_home.html) widget.